# Draw an oval exactly within the perimeter of an AWT Panel

Tags: java, applet, awt, java-2d

I want to draw an oval exactly within the panel, similar to

[image]

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
            g.drawOval(x,y,this.getHeight(), this.getHeight() );
        }
    }
```

where `x` and `y` according to `java.awt.Graphics` documentation:

> x: the x coordinate of the upper left corner of the oval to be drawn.
>
> y: the y coordinate of the upper left corner of the oval to be drawn.

So what should `x` and `y` be?

Answer (score 2):

Both `x` and `y` should be 0, as this sets the upper left corner of the oval to be at the upper left corner of the `JPanel`. Also, the line:

```
g.drawOval(x,y,this.getHeight(), this.getHeight() );
```

should actually be

```
g.drawOval(x, y, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

to ensure that the oval is drawn properly; else, it will simply be circular no matter the size of the `JPanel`.

Comment: That works. I was confused about the first and second parameters since an oval is a cornerless shape.